# DataTables draw() method is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        },
        "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
            console.log("HI");
            var s = $('td:eq(1)', nRow).text();

            if (map.hasOwnProperty(s)) $('td:eq(2)', nRow).text(map[s]);

        }
    });
    map = {
        "Accountant": "100",
        "Software Engineer": "150"
    };


    table.fnDraw();
});
```

For full code, please check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj79jmjd/1/).

Here I have assigned `map` variable after DataTables uses it. So that I need to redraw the table. But I fount that `draw()` function seems not working.

Comment: aren't u using the map variable even before assigning it..??

Comment: @Outlooker That's the reason I want to redraw the table, where it should work after redrawing. Right?

Comment: `var table=$('#example').DataTable(`  is executed  _before_ `map` is declared. You have not wondered why the error _uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined_ appear in the console in your fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#myFilter').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `map` variable before using it in `fnCreatedRow` as it gets executed before code reaches `map` initialization.

```
var map = {
    "Accountant": "100",
    "Software Engineer": "150"
};

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
        "sRowSelect": "single"
    },
    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var s = $('td:eq(1)', nRow).text();           
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(s)) $('td:eq(2)', nRow).text(map[s]);
    }
});
```

You don't need to use `fnDraw()` in this case.